# How to join two Drupal CCK content types in view without a node reference field?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-6

Users uploaded two csv files to create nodes for two CCK content types (Delivery Note and Payment), i.e.

```
 Delivery       Payment
----------     ---------
 Order No.      Order No.
 Recipient      Charge
 Address
```

I would like to create a view as a report for the boss:

```
 Order No.  Recipient  Charge
 ---------  ---------  -------
  ...        ...        $...
  ...        ...        $...
  ...        ...        $...
```

Order No. field is unique and both content types.

How's it possible to do it in Drupal's view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [View Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) with a `PHP code` field to retrive linked result via another view:

```
<?php

$order_no = $data->node_data_field_order_no_field_order_no_value;
if ($order_no) {
  $view = views_get_view('find_cck_node');
  $view->set_arguments(array('PAYMENT', $order_no));
  $view->execute();
  if (count($view->result)) {
    $value = $view->result[0]->node_data_field_payment_amount_field_payment_amount_value;
    print($value);
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe you are looking for view relationships. check out [drupal views relationships](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships)
for a video tutorial.

Comment: The video shows an example _with_ a **reference field** (user reference). I'd like to know whether it is possible to do it _without_ such a reference field.

Comment: i guess my issue here is how are you building a relationship between the tables if order no is unique for both tables?

IMHO, views can be rather limiting. sometimes its best to write your own query. i believe it was meant to help those who aren't very sql-savvy and build simple sql statements quickly.